# Generating number of weeks on Pandas dataframe, based on another Date column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I'm using the below code to generate a dataframe such as the following:

[image]

The challenge I'm facing is that the number of weeks, will end at 53.0 and then, reset back to 1.0, after which the week count continues.

[image]

I need a solution where, the number of weeks continue into 53.0, 54.0 and until the Date ends (found on the first column).

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.date_range('2006-12-16', '2010-11-26', freq='D').to_series()
s.dt.dayofweek

sample = s.dt.dayofweek
df_sample=sample.to_frame()
df_sample.rename(columns = {0: 'Day_num'}, inplace=True)

df_sample.loc[df_sample.Day_num == 5, 'Day_name'] = 'Saturday'
df_sample.loc[df_sample.Day_num == 6, 'Day_name'] = 'Sunday'
df_sample.loc[df_sample.Day_num == 0, 'Day_name'] = 'Monday'
df_sample.loc[df_sample.Day_num == 1, 'Day_name'] = 'Tuesday'
df_sample.loc[df_sample.Day_num == 2, 'Day_name'] = 'Wednesday'
df_sample.loc[df_sample.Day_num == 3, 'Day_name'] = 'Thursday'
df_sample.loc[df_sample.Day_num == 4, 'Day_name'] = 'Friday'

df_sample = df_sample['Day_name'].astype(str)
df_sample = df_sample.to_frame()

df_sample.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
df_sample.rename(columns={'index': 'Date'}, inplace=True)

df_sample['Week_Number'] = df_sample['Date'].dt.week
```

I feel there's an easier solution to this, and request any help from someone who has a better method of solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
s = pd.date_range('2006-12-16', '2010-11-26', freq='D')
df_sample=s.to_frame()
df_sample['Day_Name']=s.day_name()
df_sample=df_sample.reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={0:'Date'})
week_range=np.arange(df_sample.index[0],df_sample.index[len(df_sample.index)-1],7)
df_sample['Week_Number']=df_sample.groupby(pd.cut(df_sample.index,week_range,right=False)).ngroup(ascending=False).sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)+1
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the problem is the output, is still resetting itself from week number 53 to 1. I need a solution where the week count keeps increasing from 53 to 54, 55, 56 and until the end of the Date (seen on the first column). I don't want the week number to start afresh (after 53rd week), it needs to continue.

Comment: Only you comment the line  that contains np. where